# Jquery: Take # from input and create div

Tags: jquery

I have a few inputs which allow people to input a number (in px) for width, one for the # of columns, and another input to set the margins for each div.. Using jquery, how do I take these numbers and create these divs with the proper width and margins?

Example:

[Input] Width: 960px
[Input] # of Columns
[Input] Margins

Basically I am trying to show how the set up will be so the user will see it.

Answer (score 5):

```
var numCols = parseInt($('#columns').val());
var width = parseInt($('#width').val());
var margins = $('#margins').val();

var output = "";
for(var i=0;i<numCols;i++)
{
    output += '<div class="created">Div #'+(i+1)+'</div>';
}
$('#output').append(output);
$('.created').css(
{
    width: width+'px',
    margin: margins
});
```

This assumes the margins are passed in a valid format to be the valid of the `margin` CSS property, and that the DIVs created are placed within a container with the ID `output`

Comment: It's a good idea to include the second argument (radix) when using parseInt.

Comment: Yeah, well, the margins are passed as just a #.. I am quite new to altering the DOM like this, though I could not get what you suggested to work for me.